Contradiction in the value of $[\phi(x), v^{\mu} \partial _{\mu} \phi(x)]$ for space-like $v^{\mu}$
There seem to be two contradictory values of this commutator. I will assume Minkowski spacetime here.
On one hand, since $v^{\mu}$ is space-like, there exists a frame $(x',t')$ where $v^{\mu} \partial _{\mu}=a \partial _{x'}, a\in R$. Then, using a Lorentz transform to $(x', t')$:
$$[\phi(x), v^{\mu} \partial _{\mu} \phi(x)]$$
$$= a [\phi(x'), \partial _{x'} \phi (x')]|_{x'=\Lambda x}$$
$$=0$$
using $[\phi(x'), \nabla '\phi(x')]=0$, which follows from the CCR in the $(x',t')$ frame
On the other hand, (taking spacetime as 1+1):
$$[\phi (x), v^{\mu} \partial _{\mu} \phi (x)] = [\phi (x) , v^0 \partial _t \phi (x) + v^1 \partial _x \phi (x)]= v^0[\phi (x) , \partial _t \phi(x)]+v^1[\phi(x), \partial _x \phi (x)]= v^0 i\hbar \delta (0)$$
These approaches give two different values of this commutator. How to resolve this contradiction?

It might be clearer to write down the presumably equal time t argument in the fields, and be more explicit in the Lorentz transformation you "you-know--you-know" 'd...

Recall this.

$\delta(0)$ does not exist. This commutator is defined only for $x\neq y$.

@CosmasZachos thanks. i tried to write it more explicitly in the post. but it still does not resolve the contradiction..

@AccidentalFourierTransform but then, why don't both of the computations diverge ? The first computation gives 0...

Both Cosmas and AFT are trying to tell you that you made a wrong assumption in the commutation relations. It is precisely where the crux of the contradiction lies.

@RyderRude the problem is that when you a distribution is not a function. For example, while we are all used to writing $\delta(x)$ for the Dirac delta, this object does not really exist as a function of $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Instead it is a functional $\delta[f]=f(0)$ that evaluates a test function at zero (or some other point). The same goes for the commutators between fields. The object $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$ is a bi-distribution. You cannot simply treat it as a function and evaluate it on the diagonal $(x,x)\in \mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d$ as $[\phi(x),\phi(x)]$.

@Gold thanks. If $[\phi (x), v^{\mu}\partial _{\mu} \phi(y)= \delta (x-y)$ is a distribution, then does mean the first computation is incorrect? I also thought about phrasing this in non distribution language. Suppose we want to evaluate the distribution $[\phi(x), v^{\mu}\partial _{\mu} \phi(y)]$ when applied to a test function $f(x)$. Then the first approach gives $0$ while the second approach gives $f(y)$

There is no contraddiction.
First of all $[\phi(x), \partial_\mu \phi(x)]$ is not defined as the two arguments coincide. What we can do is to define the normal order of it
$$:[\phi(x), \partial_\mu \phi(x)]: = :\phi(x)\partial_\mu \phi(x): - :(\partial_\mu\phi(x)) \phi(x):$$
A direct computation proves that
$$:[\phi(x), \partial_\mu \phi(x)]:=0\:,$$
so no contraddiction arises through this way.
Instead CCR implies
$$[\phi(t_x,\vec{x}), v^\mu\partial_\mu \phi(t_y,\vec{y})]|_{t_x=t_y}= i\hbar v^0I\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\tag{1}$$
where both sides are intepreted as 3D distributions on test functions $f=f(\vec{x})$.
Assuming that $v$ is spacelike,  when you change reference frame in order that the components of $v$ are spatial, you must drop the constraint $t_x=t_y$. So, again, no evident contraddiction takes place.
A deeper analysis should be performed referring to $4D$-distributions.
In that case (see this site) the general form of the commutator -- which is evidently $IO(1,3)_+$ invariant -- is
$$[\phi(x),\phi(y)] =  -\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\delta(k_\mu k^\mu + m^2)\:\mbox{sign}(k_0) e^{i k_\mu(x^\mu-y^\mu)} d^4k\:.$$
It easily implies the standard commutation relations (also considering derivatives) when passing to the invariant measure on the mass shell and assuming $t_x=t_y$ in any given Minkowskian reference frame.
In summary, for a spacelike vector $v$ (which has only spatial components in the primed reference frame), both
$$[\phi(t_x,\vec{x}), v^\mu \partial_\mu\phi(t_y,\vec{y})]|_{t_x=t_y} = v^0i\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\quad \mbox{and} \quad [\phi(t'_{x'},\vec{x}'),  \sum_{k=1}^3 v'^k\partial'_k\phi(t'_{y'},\vec{y})]|_{t'_{x'}=t'_{y'}}=0$$
are correct. There is no contraddiction: they refer to different Minkowskian frames.

Thanks. I think this means that both $[\phi (x,t), v^{\mu}\partial _{\mu} (y,t)]=i\hbar \delta (x-y)$ and $[\phi (x',t'), \partial _{y'} \phi(y',t')]=0$ are correct equations. Both are taken to be equal-time in the respective frames. Is this correct?

Yes, both are correct, but they refer to different (respective) frames.

Thanks. I just thought that there would be some sort of agreement between these two equations when $v^{\mu}$ is space-like, because we could transform $v^{\mu} \partial _{\mu}$ into $a\partial _{x'}$, and we could set $x=y$ to make sure we're talking about the same commutator in both frames. But it seems like setting $x=y$ is invalid unless we do normal ordering. And if we do normal ordering, it re-establishes agreement between these two equations.

TL;DR: OP's paradox seems to be caused by ill-defined mathematical manipulations on a distributional object.
To give an idea of what may go wrong consider the following calculation for a scalar field $\phi$ with $|x|>c|t|$ spatially separated:
$$\begin{align}\overbrace{[\phi(x,t)\!-\!\phi(0,0),~\phi(0,0)]}^{=0\text{ spatially separated}} 
~=~&\overbrace{[\underbrace{\phi(x,t)\!-\!\phi(x,0)}_{\approx t\partial_t\phi(x,0)+{\cal O}(t^2)},~\phi(0,0)]}^{=0\text{ spatially separated}}\cr\cr
~+~&\overbrace{[\phi(x,0)\!-\!\phi(0,0),~\phi(0,0)]}^{=0\text{ spatially separated}}. \end{align}$$
References:

C. Itzykson & J.B. Zuber, QFT, 1985; eqs. (3-55) + (3-56) + (3-57).


Just to make sure, do you mean either of the computations is correct, or both are incorrect?
